# React list choosing option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list

I have an location app which can save name of locations.
I am trying to get each saved location a red border by clicking on it.
What it does is changing the border color of all the categories.
How can I apply that?

```
class Categories extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            term: '',
            categories: [],
            selectedCategories: [],
            hidden: true,
            checkboxState: true
        };
    }
    toggle(e) {
        this.setState({
            checkboxState: !this.state.checkboxState
        })
    }
    onChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
    }
    addCategory = (event) => {
        if (this.state.term === '') {
            alert('Please name your category!')
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.setState({
                term: '',
                categories: [...this.state.categories, this.state.term]
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="categories">
                <h1>Categories</h1>
                <div className='actions'>
                    <button className="delete" onClick={this.deleteCategory}>Delete</button>
                    <button className="edit" onClick={this.editCategory}>Edit</button>

                </div>
                <p>To add new category, please enter category name</p>
                <form className="App" onSubmit={this.addCategory}>
                    <input value={this.state.term} onChange={this.onChange} />
                    <button>Add</button>
                </form>

                {this.state.categories.map((category, index) =>
                    <button
                        key={index}
                        style={this.state.checkboxState ? { borderColor: '' } : { borderColor: 'red' }}
                        checked={this.state.isChecked}
                        onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}>
                        {category}</button>
                )}
            </div >
        );
    }
}
```

I want to be able to control each selected category seperatly, to be able to delete and edit theme as well.

Comment: Can you clarify? So if one category is selected, the others shouldn't be selected right? Which means they should have some way of communicating. Or some parent entiity regulating them

Comment: You can Select a category by clicking on it, then it became with red border. the problem is after creating more then one category, clicking on one makes all the categories became red.

Comment: That still does not answer one question. Do you want only one category selected at a time or multiple? If it's one, the parent container will have to manage that.

Comment: only one at a time.

Comment: Gotcha, so you'd need a parent container. The parent container holds all the categories and passes a method to their props. When you click the category, you pass information from the category to the parents method. I'll write up an example and post it to the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the state based on index and retrieve the similar way,

```
Code:
          {this.state.categories.map((category, index) =>
                        <button
                            key={index}
                            id={`checkboxState${index}`}
                            style={!this.state[`checkboxState${index}`] ? 
                             { borderColor: '' } : { border: '2px solid red' }}
                            checked={this.state.isChecked}
                            onClick={this.toggle}>
                            {category}</button>
                    )}

    You can see how I am checking the state dynamically this.state[`checkboxState${index}`] and also I have assigned an id to it.

    In toggle method:

     toggle = (e) => {
            const id = e.target.id;
            this.setState({
                [id]: !this.state[id]
            })
        }

FYI, this is a working code, you can see it
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vy3r73jkrl

```
Let me know if this helps you :)
```

Comment: It does! thank you very much ! I Need to understand react better :)

Comment: Awesome :). Happy react coding :).. glad to help .. you can upvote too :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really bad example using react. I'd more than likely use `this.props.children` instead of just cramming them in there. This would allow it to be more dynamic. And instead of using state names we could then just use indexes. But you'll observe, that the parent container decides which child is red by passing a method to each child. On click, the child fires the method from the parent. How you implement it can vary in a million different ways, but the overall idea should work.

```js
class ChildContainer extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);

  }
  
  render() {
    let color = this.props.backgroundColor;
    return(
      <section 
        className={'child'} 
        style={{backgroundColor: color}}
        onClick={this.props.selectMe}
      >
       
      </section>
    )
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component
{

  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props)
    
    this.state = {
      first : 'Pink',
      second : 'Pink',
      third : 'Pink',
      previous: null
    }
    this.updateChild = this.updateChild.bind(this);
  }
    
    updateChild(name)
    {
      let {state} = this;
      let previous = state.previous;
      if(previous)
      {
        state[previous] = 'Pink';
      }
      
      state[name] = 'Red';
      state.previous = name;
      this.setState(state);
    }
  
    
  render()
  {
    console.log(this)
    return(
      <section id={'parent'}>
        <ChildContainer
          selectMe={() => this.updateChild('first')}
          backgroundColor = {this.state.first}
        />
        <ChildContainer
          selectMe={() => this.updateChild('second')}
          backgroundColor = {this.state.second}
        />
        <ChildContainer
          selectMe={() => this.updateChild('third')}
          backgroundColor = {this.state.third}
        />
        
      </section>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props)
  }
  render()

  {
    return(
      <section>
        <Parent/>
        
      </section>
    )
  }
}


React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to track the state of every checkbox, possibly have an array with all currently checked checkboxes.

Then instead of `this.state.checkboxState` in `this.state.checkboxState ? { borderColor: '' } : { borderColor: 'red' }` you need to check if current category is in the currently checked categories array.

Hope this helps

Comment: I really wish, when a vote down is given to state the reason. This does not help me nor the users who will stumble upon this question.

Comment: I think if you can share sample code based on your explanation then it might help :D